# swift UIView.animate skips animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I have custom class inheriting from UIScrollView, which contains "Close button"  view. By pressing "Close button", I would like to make an animation - scale transformation and then remove whole view from SuperView.

```
class AddReview : UIScrollView { 

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let closeButton = CloseButtonView()
    closeButton.frame = CGRect(x:frame.maxX - 50, y:0, width: 50, height: 50)
    self.addSubview(closeButton)

    let tapCloseGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(closeButtonPressed))
    closeButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    closeButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapCloseGestureRecognizer)
}

func closeButtonPressed(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3){
       self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
       self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        if (finished)
        {
            //self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    })
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

My problem here is that no animation occur. A view is removed immediately, or when `removeFromSuperview` is commented out it's resized to its 10% with no animation.

I've tried to use `layoutIfNeeded`, Dispatch of main queue, and plenty of other things, but nothig was working.

What's more, I've noticed sometimes it's working, but most of the time it's not working!

Any idea what could be an issue please?
Thanks a lot for any advice :)

Comment: The second `UIView.animate` does not wait until the first one has completed. The second one starts before the first one has finished so, I'm guessing, the second one overrides the first and removed the view. You'll need to chain them if you want them to run one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Magnas has stated, the second animation is called before the first one has a chance to complete. Try:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
    // wait for first animation to complete
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        if (finished)
        {
            //self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    })
})
```

This can be slightly shortened:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
    // wait for first animation to complete
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    }, completion: { finished in
        if (finished)
        {
            //self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you Aleks, this seems to work. But not while debugging, once debugger is detached, I have to manually kill the app, restart app and then it's working.